# Show that every maximal solution to $x'=G(x)$ is defined in an interval $(a,\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a function $G:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ locally lipschitz, suppose there exists $R>0$ such that $x\cdot G(x)\leq 0 , \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $||x||\geq R$. Show that every maximal solution to $x'=G(x)$ is defined in an interval $(a,\infty)$.

By the Picar's theorem I know there exists a solution to $x'=G(x)$ on the shape of $\gamma:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}^d$. And $a,b$ can be infinite. I don't know how to get to the proof.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What book did you get this exercise from? I would like to see some more related exercises.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For the existence of the solution define $x'=f(t,x)=G(x)$, since $G$ is Lipschitz on $x$ it follows that $f$ is Lipschitz on the second variable, so the Theorem of Picard applies. This solution is maximal, on the interval $(a,\infty)$ because the norm of $x$ is decreasing for $\|x\|\geq R$. To see this, notice that $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\, x,x\rangle = 2\langle\,x,x'\rangle = 2\langle\,x,G(x)\rangle=2x\cdot G(x)\leq 0 $$